# how to make an eloquent result into an array Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I want to combine two data search results into one array, I use `array_merge` but there is an `array_merge()` error:

> Argument # 1 is not an array

How to turn `$vendor`'s eloquent results into an array and combine it with `$plucked`?

```
$vendor = Vendor::find($id);
$vendor_detail = VendorDetail::where('vendor_id',$id)->get();
$plucked = $vendor_detail->pluck('vendor_profile_value','vendor_profile_name');

$coba = array_merge($vendor,$plucked);
```

`$plucked` already an array
I think the problem here is that `$vendor` is not yet an array

Comment: `pluck()->all();`

Comment: i tried that but get an error Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::pluck(),

Comment: `pluck('vendor_profile_value','vendor_profile_name')->all()`

Comment: $plucked already an array, the problem is in $vendor

Comment: `get()->all()` should work.

Comment: no sir, the result after dd being like this, this is not what I want
 0 => App\Models\Vendor\Penjual\Vendor {#1129 ▶}
  1 => App\Models\Vendor\Penjual\Vendor {#1130 ▶}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
$vendor = Vendor::find($id);
$vendorDetails = VendorDetail::query()
             ->select('vendor_profile_value', 'vendor_profile_name')
             ->where('vendor_id', $id)
             ->get()
             ->toArray();

$coba = array_merge($vendor, $vendorDetails);
```

The `get()` method execute the query returning a [Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-collections) instance, in which you can call the [`toArray()`](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections#method-toarray) method.

---

### Side note

As far as I can see, you could make use of [relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) and [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading).

If you have a [one-to-many relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) defined like this in your `Vendor` model:

```
public function details()
{
    return $this->hasMany(VendorDetails::class);
}
```

Then, you could [eager load](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) the relationship like this:

```
$vendor = Vendor::with('details')->find($id);
//                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You could even just load the wanted fields:

```
$vendor = Vendor::with('details:vendor_profile_value,vendor_profile_name')
                ->find($id);
```

Then, your object will have a new attribute called "details" containing the related objects (or a collection of the limited selected fields).

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the $vendor to an Array like below.

```
$vendor = Vendor::find($id)->toArray();
```